# android Button inside custom listview

Tags: android, listview, button

I have developed an Android application using custom `ListView`. My custom `ListView` consists of `Textview`, `ImageView` and 2 `ImageButton`s. I want to change my `ImageButton`'s resource when I click it. (example: from play to stop). More clearly, I attach my design below.

[image]

How can I control my `ImageButton` from `Activity`?

```
public class MyCustomBaseAdapterSurat extends BaseAdapter {
    private static ArrayList<SearchResults> searchArrayList;

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    ViewHolder holder;
    private StreamingMediaPlayer audioStreamer;

    public MyCustomBaseAdapterSurat(Context context,
            ArrayList<SearchResults> results) {
        searchArrayList = results;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return searchArrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return searchArrayList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.customlistsurat, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            holder.iv = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            holder.play = (ImageButton) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
            holder.rep = (ImageButton) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
             holder.play.setOnClickListener(klikplay);
        //   holder.rep.setOnClickListener(klikrep);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.rep.setId(searchArrayList.get(position).getIdRep());
        holder.play.setId(searchArrayList.get(position).getIdPlay());
        holder.txtName.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getName());
        holder.iv.setBackgroundResource(searchArrayList.get(position)
                .getDrawable());
        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtName;
        ImageView iv;
        ImageButton play;
        ImageButton rep;
    }

    private OnClickListener klikplay = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            holder.play.setBackgroundResource(searchArrayList.get(v.getId())
                    .getDrawable());
            //startStreamingAudio();
        }
    };

}
```

Comment: Why not extending from `ArrayAdapter` if your underlying data is `ArrayList`?

Comment: after setting ur background image, call setadapter again to refresh ur list